# TikZ: shaded area enveloping a graph

Tags: graph, latex, drawing, tikz

I need to draw a shaded area enveloping a graph like in the example below. I am looking for an automated procedure and a more satisfying result. Compared to the example, I need smoother edges and more regular distances between vertices (circles) and the boundaries of the area.

Drawing arbitrary shapes in TikZ are time consuming, I suspect that a smart trick might do the job, like creating large overlapping areas centered at each vertex. Any suggestions?

[image]

And here is a minimal working LaTeX code to generate the graph which has to be enveloped:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,draw=black,thick]

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \pos/\name in {{(0,1)/1}, {(1,1)/2}, {(0,0)/3}, {(1,0)/4}, {(2,0)/5}, {(1,-.7)/6}}
            \node[vertex] (\name) at \pos {};
            
        \foreach \one/\two in {{1/2}, {1/3}, {1/4}, {1/6}, {2/3}, {2/4}, {2/5}, {3/6}, {4/6}, {4/5}}
            \draw[thick] (\one) -- (\two);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could connect your nodes with a polygon with a tick stroke:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

    \tikzset{vertex/.style={circle,draw=black,thick}}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \pos/\name in {{(0,1)/1}, {(1,1)/2}, {(0,0)/3}, {(1,0)/4}, {(2,0)/5}, {(1,-.7)/6}}
            \node[vertex] (\name) at \pos {};
            
        \foreach \one/\two in {{1/2}, {1/3}, {1/4}, {1/6}, {2/3}, {2/4}, {2/5}, {3/6}, {4/6}, {4/5}}
            \draw[thick] (\one) -- (\two);
            
        
       \begin{scope}[on background layer]   
          \filldraw[lightgray,line width=20pt,rounded corners=5pt] (1.center) --  (2.center) --  (5.center) --  (4.center) --  (6.center) --  (3.center) -- cycle;
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]